# sharedpreferences and radioButtons i can't make one radiobutton state saved correctly

Tags: java, android, radio-button, sharedpreferences, android-radiogroup

as the title says i can't make it work for some reason 
i tried debugging but couldn't find the problem, every time when i click on radio_button_B  it gets stuck on it and never change to radio_button_A

```
static RadioGroup radio_group;
RadioButton radio_button_A;
RadioButton radio_button_B;
private SharedPreferences sp_for_radio;
```

onCreate

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_leaderboard);
```

//id

```
    radio_group = findViewById(R.id.radio_group);
    radio_button_A = findViewById(R.id.team_a_radio);
    radio_button_B = findViewById(R.id.team_b_radio);
```

//SP getBoolean

```
    sp_for_radio  = getSharedPreferences("sp_radio", MODE_PRIVATE);
    radio_button_A.setChecked(sp_for_radio.getBoolean("team_a_rb", false));
    radio_button_B.setChecked(sp_for_radio.getBoolean("team_b_rb", false));
```

// onChecked

```
    radio_group.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor2 = sp_for_radio.edit();
            RadioButton checkedRadioButton = group.findViewById(checkedId);
            // This puts the value (true/false) into the variable
            boolean isChecked = checkedRadioButton.isChecked();

            //

            if (isChecked) {

                if (radio_button_A.getId()==checkedRadioButton.getId()){
                    editor2.putBoolean("team_a_rb", isChecked);
                    editor2.apply();
                }else if (radio_button_B.getId() == checkedRadioButton.getId()){
                    editor2.putBoolean("team_b_rb", isChecked);
                    editor2.apply();
                }
            }
        }
    });


}
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT :

if (isChecked) {

```
                if (radio_button_A.getId()==checkedRadioButton.getId()){
                    editor2.putBoolean("team_a_rb", isChecked);
                    editor2.putBoolean("team_b_rb", false);
                    editor2.apply();
                }else if (radio_button_B.getId() == checkedRadioButton.getId()){
                    editor2.putBoolean("team_b_rb", isChecked);
                    editor2.putBoolean("team_a_rb", false);
                    editor2.apply();
                }
            }
```

Comment: i've edited the question can u check it again? please